# Where can I find Chumash and Rashi review questions

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, rashi, pentateuch-chumash

Where can I find Chumash and Rashi review questions on all books of the Torah?

Looking for:

1. As much detailed question as possible (i.e the more questions on as much rashi's as possible the more questions on each Rashi.)
2. Any Age group.
3. Words to translate would be great.
4. Better if it is online but if it is in a book it is fine (it would be great to get a sample page of that book if you can find a sample page.)
5. English, Hebrew, or Yiddish questions.

Comment: Hey, 7179, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thank you for your question....[edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/46196/edit)ing in motivation for the question would improve it (why do you want review questions? for what age group, adult or child?)

Comment: You might want to consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features, as well as choosing a more interesting name than "user7179," unless that happens to be your favorite number ;)

Comment: Not online but this is a link to a set of books with 100+ questions on each parsha to choose from. http://www.judaicapress.com/The-Rashi-Companion-5-vol.-set.html

Comment: The Rashi Companion is perfect

Comment: New working link for: The Rashi Companion. Author: Rabbi Yaakov Marcus. Publisher: Judaica Press.  https://judaicaplaza.com/products/jp-raco5v

Answer (score 4):

Rabbi Wichnin's Chumash Questions book, first edition of which, published in 1995, is long since out of print, is now available online at
http://www.chumashquestions.org/

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya dub! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It could be further improved with a brief description of the book and the sorts of questions it asks.

Answer (score 3):

[Ohr Same'ach](http://ohr.edu/this_week/parsha_q_and_a/)

Two other sites that I know are good are Torah Tots and OU's NCSY site. I have trouble locating these sites, now, but if you Google, you should locate these, as well as numerous other sites.

You may also want to check various shul and yeshiva web sites. Many yeshivot & kolelim post parsha questions on their web site. Yeshivot ketanot (elementary school) tend to do this as they use this for homework.

Answer (score 2):

I found this recently the rashi challenge http://www.feldheim.com/the-rashi-quiz-book.html.

Brief description from feldheim: Learning Chumash with Rashi has been a treasured part of Jewish life for almost a thousand years, since the time he lived and wrote. Now, Rabbi Jonathan Fox, with his engaging question-and-answer format, brings the enjoyable gift of Rashi to our Shabbos tables every week. The Rashi Challenge makes the power and wisdom of Rashi’s teachings accessible to all young and old, learned and beginner in a delightful and fascinating way.

Comment: New working link [https://www.feldheim.com/the-rashi-quiz-book-1](https://www.feldheim.com/the-rashi-quiz-book-1)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the 'What's bothering Rashi?' series [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0873068491):

He provides Rashi's insight on a pasuk and then provides a greater analysis to understanding his train of thought.

You can find some examples [here](https://www.aish.com/tp/i/wbr/).

---

**EDIT**

Artscroll are now rolling out an *[Elucidated Rashi on Chumash](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422639030.html)*

The blurb there reads as follows:

> For centuries, the brilliant light of Rashi – Rav Shlomo ben Yitzchak of medieval France - has illuminated the world of Torah, earning him the esteemed title of "The Father of Commentators." With unrivaled clarity and grace, Rashi's commentary on the Torah has become an integral – and truly indispensable – part of Chumash study.
>
> There are more people studying Torah today than ever before, and their level of knowledge and sophistication is higher than ever. They know that beneath the deceptively straightforward exterior of Rashi's commentary lies a depth that has captivated the intellects of esteemed talmidei chachamim for more than eight centuries, and they wish to dig a bit deeper, to understand not just what Rashi says, but the underlying concepts. They want to gain a deeper look into Rashi’s thought process and better understand those places where the commentators disagree with Rashi. What motivated Rashi with his specific remark? How does the wording in the Torah reveal Rashi's intent? To which passage in the Targum does Rashi allude?
>
> This new series will take you to a whole new level of understanding of the foremost commentary on Chumash. It will satisfy scholar, student and layman alike, and will become recognized as the standard comprehensive treatment of Rashi.
>
> The Elucidated Rashi on Chumash features:
>
> - An expanded translation and elucidation, written in a contemporary, readable style, and drawing upon the major commentaries on Rashi.
> - A short introduction to each Rashi, providing a preview of the topic.
> - Notes discussing “What’s bothering Rashi?”
> - Insights containing in-depth analysis of Rashi’s words.
> - Explanations of underlying concepts and deeper looks into those places where the commentators disagree with Rashi.
> - The Elucidated Rashi belongs in every Torah home. Regardless of your level of knowledge or scholarship, The Elucidated Rashi will enhance your understanding of the foundational Chumash commentary.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple choice questions on each Parsha go to https://chumashrashitests.com/#test