# Where can I find mishneh torah review questions?

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, rambam

Looking for review question and answers on the mishneh torah? Either sections or the entirety.

Similar to this question [Where can I find Chumash and Rashi review questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46196/where-can-i-find-chumash-and-rashi-review-questions)

I am aware of Rabbi Gordons lecture on chabad.org and also theirs and sefaria translations which are great. I was wondering if someone had created review questions and answers similar to the rashi question mentioned above or like on what http://dafyomi.co.il/ provides on gemara.

Thank you

Comment: I doubt such a thing exists. People don't study the Rambam's _Mishneh Torah_ as much as Rashi's commentary on the _Chumash_ or _Daf Yomi_. But it's a good question, nevertheless, and I'm interested to see what people on here might come up with! +1

Answer (score 3):

I've never tried them myself, but the Master Torah program has [over 151,000 questions on the Mishnah Torah](http://www.mastertorah.com/newsite/shiurim/list_shiurim.php?shiurtype=rambam_questions).

Comment: Excellent answer, +1, but as per what is known about the creator/administrator of the Master Torah program (https://www.google.ca/search?q=meir+pogrow&oq=meir+pogrow&aqs=chrome..69i57.4586j0j7&client=ms-android-polaroid&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8), it has been suggested that each individual ask their Rav before using the program or its resources.

Comment: Thanks for the ressource Menachem but I feel very hesitant about accepting this as an answer as what רבות מחשבות brings up.